# Cant Search By NDC String

Tags: api, openfda

Hello I know this may be a dumb question but I would like to search for a drug by the NDC like this `https://api.fda.gov/drug/ndc.json?search=product_ndc:"54868-4517"&limit=100` but I get a

```
{
error: {
code: "NOT_FOUND",
message: "No matches found!"
  }
}
```

as the result. Would love any suggestions with this thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is syntactically correct; there are simply no matches in the NDC directory itself. Using the example you provided, `54868-4517` appears to match *ADVAIR DISKUS- fluticasone propionate and salmeterol powder*, which has been inactivated by the FDA:

[image]